# How do you convert an OpenAPI Spec (Swagger 2.0) to proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, code-generation, openapi

I've done extensive Google searching but couldn't find a good tool to do this. The closest I could find was https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic, which allows converting an OpenAPI description (swagger.yaml) into a .pb file or a .json file. I'm wondering if there are any tools to convert this .pb file into a .proto proto3 file?

I also tried https://github.com/NYTimes/openapi2proto but unfortunately there are a few cases that aren't handled correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but I was wandering the same and it seems that things have changed in meantime. So I will post an answer for others, lazy enough to search :)

Currently there are several options to convert OpenApi 2/3 to Protobuf:

- **OpenAPITools/openapi-generator** supports this from version 4.1.2, find more [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/3818).
- **googleapis/gnostic** can do this as well, find more [here](https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic).
- **nytimes/openapi2proto** a tool written in go for this, find more [here](https://github.com/nytimes/openapi2proto).
- maybe some more...? add if i missed any.

Comment: How to be sure that generated protobuf fields will have the same numbers after adding/deleting some fields from OpenApi file?

Comment: I guess - only by testing! If you do not trust lib authors enough, you have to write your won tests to prove that it works just as you expect :)